# JS: Sort a multi-dimensional array based on each sub-array's length

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is re-order the multidimensional array based on the lengths of each of its arrays, highest to lowest.

```
var array0 = [9, 7, 1]    
var array1 = [2]
var array2 = [20, 3, 8, 11]
var array3 = [0, 6];

var multi = [array0, array1, array2, array3];

var multiLengths = [];

$(multi).each(function(i) { // for loop using jQuery
    multiLengths.push(this.length);
});
// multiLengths: 3,1,4,2

function sortDesc(a,b) { //sort in descending order
    return b - a;
}

multiLengths.sort(sortDesc);

// somehow re-order multi to be: [array2, array0, array3, array1]
```

So how would I reorder the 'multi' array based on the new sorted order of 'multiLengths'? It's difficult because the new order is created using the sort function, so I can't really index the results of the sortedMulti array.

Comment: I don't get why you need jQuery to loop through an ordinary array. Even if you use jQuery, the proper way to loop through that array would be `$.each(multilengths, fn)`.

Comment: probably cuz I'm not that great a javascript, but I do know that the way I did it works proper or not. PS proper by who's standards?

Comment: I don't need to reference any standard for that. Have a look at JavaScripts `for` loops, they are faster than jQuerys `.each` and it's simply and overkill to import a 30KB library for looping through arrays.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that. Thanks. I will say, I'm using sortable. So the 30K isn't going to waste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use sort on `multi` directly:

```
multi.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.length - a.length;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(multi).each(function(i) { // for loop using jQuery
    multiLengths.push([this.length, this]);
});

function sortDesc(a,b) { //sort in descending order
    return b[0] - a[0];
}
```

and then when you're done sorting `multiLengths`, just map the result to the element `[1]`.

It's not as useful in this context, probably (@FelixLoether's answer is much simpler), but in case you need a more complex calculation than `.length`, this way of caching and sorting is rather efficient.

Comment: I'm confused by the [0] added on to b - a... Any way you could explain it to me?

Comment: Instead of making an array of lengths alone, I made an array of lengths *along with the original elements*. Then you sort these by lengths (which are stored in the first (i.e `[0]`) element). The original element tags along and ends up in its sorted position. Then you just extract the element itself (the `[1]`), and discard the cached length.